Submitting data once a file is uploaded not when submit is clicked
I have a form and am trying to call my api when a file is uploaded. Currently it only works when the user clicks a submit button. How can I get it to call my api with handleFileChange? The fetch request only works in for the handleSubmit function. Here is my html:
  <form className={styles['resume-form']} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="relative">
            <input
              type="file"
              accept=".pdf, .doc, .docx"
              id="fileInput"
              className="hidden"
              onChange={handleFileChange}
            />
            <label
              htmlFor="fileInput"
              className="bg-yellow-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded cursor-pointer hover:bg-yellow-600"
            >
              Choose a file
            </label>
          </div>        
        <button type="submit" id="reviewer" className={styles['submit-button']}>Submit</button>
      </form>

Here is my javascript code:
const handleFileChange = async (e) => {
    setResumeFile(e.target.files[0]);
    console.log("test")

    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      console.log("test1")
      formData.append('resume', resumeFile);
      const response = await fetch('/api/analyze_resume', {
              method: 'POST',
              body: formData,
              headers: {
                // Note: No need to set 'Content-Type' for FormData as it is automatically set
              },
      });

      const responseData = await response.json();
      setReviewResult(responseData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting resume:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleFileUpload = async (file) => {
    setResumeFile(file);
     e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('resume', resumeFile);
      const response = await fetch('/api/analyze_resume', {
              method: 'POST',
              body: formData,
              headers: {
                // Note: No need to set 'Content-Type' for FormData as it is automatically set
              },
            });

      const responseData = await response.json();
      setReviewResult(responseData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting resume:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('resume', resumeFile);
      const response = await fetch('/api/analyze_resume', {
              method: 'POST',
              body: formData,
              headers: {
                // Note: No need to set 'Content-Type' for FormData as it is automatically set
              },
            });

      const responseData = await response.json();
      setReviewResult(responseData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting resume:', error);
    }
  };


You appear to already be making a request to an API in your handleFileChange function.  Is that failing in some way?

Already voted to close, but this also appears to be a duplicate of: The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately  (I'm assuming you're using React, though it's not explicitly indicated in the question.)

trying to call my api when a file is uploaded. Currently it only works when the user clicks a submit button., but would you want to have both submit button and also make API call when file is selected?

@David Yes its not calling it

@mrconcerned When the file is selected it should call the api. Currently I have the api fetch request ready but it only works for the submit button click.

@chackerian: If the handleFileChange function isn't being called at all then that's a very different problem from anything related to an API.  Can you reduce that to a [mcve] which demonstrates specifically and only the problem you're trying to describe?  Currently the question, and the code therein, is primarily focused on calling an API, which is downstream from calling the function at all and unrelated to that operation.

@chackerian: Or did you mean that the function is being called, but the API is not?  Basically, when you say "its not calling it", what is "it" and what is "it"?  Is "it" being called, but "it" is somehow failing to call "it"?  How are you observing both "it" and "it"?  What debugging have you done?  When you debug, which specific operation in the code shown is failing, and how specifically does that operation fail?

You can just use e.target.files[0] as:
formData.append('resume', e.target.files[0]);

instead of setting it in a state and using it.

But this doesn't call my api.

It has to run:
const response = await fetch('/api/analyze_resume', {
method: 'POST',
body: formData,
headers: {
// Note: No need to set 'Content-Type' for FormData as it is automatically set
},
});

@chackerian if I try your code it works just fine, so you have to share more information maybe to help us understand.

It works only when the submit button is pressed. It's supposed to work when the file is added immediately then.
